# Which context does BroadcastReceivers receive when listening for BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

AlarmManagers in Android lose all of their registered alarms when phone loses power.

I use the following broadcast receiver to trigger at android bootup:

```
public class AlarmBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Cursor alarmCursor = MainActivity.dbHelper.loadAlarms();
            // Iterate through every stored alarm and set those alarms.
            // ....
            alarmCursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

- When the broadcast receiver's onReceive is triggered at system bootup, what context parameter is given to the method? I have to know the context, because I need the context to cancel alarms set in that context.
- I am assuming the call to MainActivity.dbHelper.loadAlarms() is not safe because MainActivity is not initialized in system bootup. Or is it safe because dbhelper and loadAlarms() are all initialized and declared static?

Comment: The type of context does not matter, more importantly you shouldn't be handling that yourself. There exist multiple solutions for this in the framework or Google libraries. First option: Job sheduler api. Second option: tasks scheduled using the GcmNetworkMamager. Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the broadcast receiver's `onReceive` is triggered at system bootup, what context parameter is given to the method? I have to know
>   the context, because I need the context to cancel alarms set in that
>   context.

You will get the global application `Context` in `onReceive()` in this case. However, it is irrelevant. You don't need to know.

To cancel the alarms later, you will create a `PendingIntent` and you can use any `Context` you want to do this. Alarms are not linked to a specific `Context`, they are only linked to a specific application.

> I am assuming the call to MainActivity.dbHelper.loadAlarms() is not
>   safe because MainActivity is not initialized in system bootup. Or is
>   it safe because dbhelper and loadAlarms() are all initialized and
>   declared `static`?

If `dbHelper` is indeed `static` and initialized at instance creation (**not in `onCreate()`**), then this call is fine. In general, calling static methods on activities is frowned upon, as it is easy to do something stupid assuming that the `Activity` has been correctly set up. You would be better off moving such static methods to a general utilities class, which is not an `Activity` and only contains `static` methods. This would look less suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what type of `Context` your BroadcastReceiver receives (In any case, its `ApplicationContext`) because :
1) You should not use a DBHelper which is associated with an `Activity`. Instead, make it a Singleton and use it throughout your app.
2) Your `AlarmManager` should be set using a `Service`. So, its good idea to call the service in your `onReceive()` and set the Alarms from that service

Comment: Oh that makes sense. So should DBHelper be a static class with static methods? Or is that different from implementing it as a singleton? I am unsure because making the DBHelper initializable means I have to keep it as a variable somewhere. So different activities will instantiate that singleton, assuming my implementation is thread-safe?

Comment: Singleton is different from static. A simple google search leads to this : https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992

Comment: Don't use singletons.